# Regex to select all character between underscores

Tags: java, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write a regular expression to select all characters between underscores. I end up with `_([^_]+)_` but it does not match all the groups,

String : `abc_bca_vag_hag_bag`
output : `bca vag hag`

can someone help with this?

Comment: Do you expect an answer using Java or Python, or either is fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex will *match* the underscores, and things that are matched once will not be matched again. So after matching `_bca_`, it does not see that the last underscore in `_bca_` is actually the same underscore that is before `vag`. It thinks that `vag` is not preceded by an underscore because it has already matched the underscore preceding it in the previous match.

You need to use *lookaheads* and *lookbehinds*:

```
(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)
```

These will not match the underscore. They will only "look" and see whether there is an underscore.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G7FtkQ/1)

Answer (score 4):

I used split function and select every elements except first one and last one:

```
st = 'abc_bca_vag_hag_bag'
lis = st.split('_')[1:-1]
# output  ['bca', 'vag', 'hag']
```